# I'm having trouble with NextJs useRouter

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm having trouble with NextJs useRouter.

I have a function to navigate between paths, and I use useRouter to do that, I wrote in a library that contains an array object:

```
router = useRouter()

const actions = [
  {
  ...
    perform: (e) => router.push('/'),
  ...
  }
]
```

But it causes the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`

```
  2 | import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
  3 | 
> 4 | const { router } = useRouter()
    |                            ^
  5 | 
  6 | const actions = [
  7 |   {
```

I imported this library to another component, this is what the `_app.js` looks like:

```
...
<div className={'webkit selection'+theme}>
   <CmdBar theme={theme}/>  => this is where the library imported in
   <Metatags description='null'/>
   <StyleReset/>
   <Component themeUse={themeUse.styles} theme={theme} {...pageProps} />
   <Bar theme={theme} setTheme={setTheme} setThemeUse={setThemeUse} themeProvider={themeProvider}/>
</div>
...
```

I have had this error the same as I used `useLocation` in React and React Router before because the components are outside the Route. I think it's the main causes of these.

**Edited:** It won't keep the same UI if I use anything that can refresh the page, so this is what I want to figure out.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I wrapped all the stuff in _app.js

Answer (score 6):

Hi the issue is occuring because you're using a react hook on top level.
Instead you should be using the hook inside your React Functional component.

Something like this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function ActiveLink({ href }) {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <a href={href}>
      This will redirect
    </a>
  )
}

export default ActiveLink
```

I'd recommend you to go through, [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, you're calling useRouter immediately after imports and not inside your component. Hooks need too be called inside React functional components.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

i.e.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
 
const actions = [..]

const Component = () => {
     const router = useRouter() // use it here

     ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've probably already discovered this by now, but I followed a suggest ion to use Next Router without using a hook in my api (.ts) library.

```
import Router from 'next/router';

// Use directly
Router.push('/404');
```